# How to convert a list of selected choices into columns of yes/no values for all possible choices

Tags: excel

I have used a Google Form to survey 100 people. The last question was a checkbox question where people could choose up to 5 options. Google has output this data as a box with their 5 choices separated by commas. I know how to split this into up to 5 cells with one choice in each. However, I would like to split it into 16 cells (one for each possible option) with a yes or no in each cell depending on whether the person chose it.

I have tried to find this under make columns from cells but with no luck.

Comment: Any image with the output?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way of doing it:
Use the Text to Columns function to split the data into separate cells.
Then create the headings for the extra columns. Assuming the title for the first option is in AA1 and the first cell containing a choice is in M2, use this function in AA2:

`=IF(OR($M2=AA$1, $N2=AA$1, $O2=AA$1, $P2=AA$1, $Q2=AA$1, $R2=AA$1), 1, 0)`

Then drag it to populate the rest of your table with 1s and 0s.